# ASP.NET Core Web API - Issues with Autofac and EF Core when using InstancePerRequest()

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

I am trying to set up my **ASP.NET Core Web API** project with **Autofac**, **EF Core** and **AutoMapper**.

Currently I am able to make my project work with the following two setups:

- Register everything as a singelton => `SingleInstance()` *(concurrency issues with EF Context as it isn't thread safe)*
- Register everything so that it gets a new instance everytime `Resolve()` is called => `InstancePerDependency()` *(additional overhead)*

Unfortunately, I am not able to make it work with the `InstancePerRequest()` scope.

For some reason I get the following error message:

[image]

This sounds a bit like I would be injecting those `InstancePerRequest()` dependencies somewhere in a `singelton` service ...

Once I change everything to to `SingleInstance()` or `InstancePerDependency()` everything works fine. At least not counting the the concurrency issues and additional overhead compared to `InstancePerRequest()`.

### Startup.cs

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Is called by the ASP.NET Core application for all environments.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="builder">Builder container.</param>
    private static void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder, ApplicationName applicationName)
    {
        // For all environments and for only user service specific registrations
        if (applicationName == ApplicationName.XY)
        {

            // Auto mapper
            builder.RegisterAutoMapper();

            // Register db context
            builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>().InstancePerRequest();

            // Repositories
            builder.RegisterType<RepositoryA>().As<IRepositoryA>().InstancePerRequest();

            // Services
            builder.RegisterType<ServiceA>().As<IServiceA>().InstancePerRequest();
        }
    }

     /// <summary>
    /// Register AutoMapper to the DI container.
    /// </summary>
    public static void RegisterAutoMapper(this ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(c => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            // Mapping
            cfg.CreateMap<EntityA, EntityB>();


        })).AsSelf().SingleInstance();

        // Register mapper
        builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper(c.Resolve)).As<IMapper>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
```

### Service A

```
public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IRepositoryA _repository;

    public ServiceA (IRepositoryA _repository, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _repository = _repository;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return all categories.
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<List<XY>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await _repository.XY.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

### Repository A

```
 public class RepositoryA : RepositoryBase<XY, int, RepositoryA>, IRepositoryA
    {
        public RepositoryA(MyDbContext myDbContext, ILogger<RepositoryA> logger) : base(myDbContext, logger)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

### RepositoryBase

```
 public abstract class RepositoryBase<TEntityType, TIdType, TLoggingType>
    where TEntityType : class
    where TLoggingType : class
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _myDbContext;

    protected readonly ILogger<TLoggingType> _logger;
    protected DbSet<TEntityType> _dbSet;

    private bool _disposed = false;

    public RepositoryBase(MyDbContext myDbContext, ILogger<TLoggingType> logger)
    {
        _myDbContext = myDbContext;
        _dbSet = _myDbContext.Set<TEntityType>();
        _logger = logger;
    }


    // All the boilerplate code has been left out for the sake of brevity
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** - it is possible but `InstancePerLifetimeScope()` still should be the first option to consider. Also, autofac's documentation is not entirely correct - the behavior will not be exactly the same.

First of all, please read [how InstancePerRequest() works](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html#how-per-request-lifetime-works) in full .NET Framework WebAPI application. As it's outlined under the link it actually uses `InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope()` under the hood to get job done.

Next question is - how `InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope()` works? :) That, in turn, is described [here](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-matching-lifetime-scope). Example below shows the idea behind it.

```
public interface IMyService { }

public class MyService: IMyService
{ 
    public MyService()
    { 
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IMyService>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("ScopeName");
        var container = builder.Build();

        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("ScopeName"))
        {
            var instance1 = scope.BeginLifetimeScope().Resolve<IMyService>();
            var instance2 = scope.BeginLifetimeScope().Resolve<IMyService>();
            // This outputs "True" since both instances are actually resolved from the same lifetime scope
            // tagged with string "ScopeName".
            // If none of the parent scopes are tagged with the "ScopeName" 
            // then such an attempt to resolve IMyService will throw an exception.
            Console.WriteLine($"References are the same: {object.ReferenceEquals(instance1, instance2)}");
        }
    }
}
```

So, what happens when WebAPI receives a request? Autofac hook in the WebAPI pipeline creates new scope tagged with `Autofac.Core.Lifetime.MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag` constant (it's "AutofacWebRequest" string). This scope becomes "root" for this particular request. Controller and all its stuff gets resolved from that scope as well, and all attempts to resolve dependencies registered with `InstancePerRequest()`, i.e. with `InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest")`, go up to that scope.

Now, let's get back to .NET Core. Microsoft implemented their own DI management and it is now embedded in the WebAPI as well. It works pretty much the same way with one exception: Microsoft's DI does not have a concept of "tagged" scopes, so it just don't have any means to provide functionality similar to `InstancePerRequest()`. Instead, WebAPI internals just create new ordinary scope, i.e. make `BeginLifetimeScope()` call in autofac's terms. That allows controllers to resolve their own instances of `DbContext`s and other stuff that are unique to the request. So, as Travis have already pointed out, the simplest and most straightforward way to handle such a dependencies in the .NET Core is to use `InstancePerLifetimeScope()` registrations (or "scoped" in terms of Microsoft's DI container), since that's what WebAPI does internally anyway. That's the first option you should consider in .NET Core. **And that's where behavior is different from per-request scopes of autofac.**

However, in my opinion the concept of `InstancePerRequest()` registrations is still valid and has the right to exist even though it should be very rarely needed. Luckily, it's not very hard to implement it yourself. You need few major things:

1. Autofac;
2. Register all controllers as a services using `AddControllersAsServices()` extension;
3. Middleware that receives a request, creates tagged lifetime scope, and puts that scope as a DI container in the request, so that all downstream things - middlewares, controllers, etc. - used that container to resolve their dependencies;
4. extension to register that middleware;
5. custom `InstancePerRequest()` extension to register dependencies using your own lifetime scope tag.

So, all in all possible implementation could be like the following.

**Test service to play with:**

```
public interface ISomeService
{
    Guid Id { get; }
}

public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    public Guid Id { get; }

    public SomeService()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

**TestController.cs**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;

    public TestController(ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        _scope = scope;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var service1 = _scope.Resolve<ISomeService>();
        ISomeService service2;
        using (var newScope = _scope.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            service2 = newScope.Resolve<ISomeService>();
        }
        return Ok(service1.Id == service2.Id);
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddMvc()
            .AddControllersAsServices();

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        // just to play with another option and see how it works
//        builder.RegisterType<SomeService>().As<ISomeService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<SomeService>().As<ISomeService>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.Populate(services);

        return new AutofacServiceProvider(builder.Build());
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        // !!!!!
        app.UsePerRequestScopes();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Now to the essential part. I did not pull it from my working project, so it may not be completely correct but it works and it shows the idea very well.

**RequestScopeMiddleware.cs**

```
public class RequestScopeMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly string _scopeName;

    public RequestScopeMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, string scopeName)
    {
        _next = next;
        _scopeName = scopeName;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var originalServiceProvider = context.RequestServices;
        var currentLifetimeScope = originalServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILifetimeScope>();
        using (var requestScope = currentLifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope(_scopeName))
        {
            context.RequestServices = new AutofacServiceProvider(requestScope);
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            finally
            {
                context.RequestServices = originalServiceProvider;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

**RequestScopeExtensions.cs**

```
public static class RequestScopeExtensions
{
    private const string ScopeName = "RequestScope";

    public static void InstancePerRequest<T1, T2, T3>(this IRegistrationBuilder<T1, T2, T3> builder)
    {
        builder.InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(ScopeName);
    }

    public static void UsePerRequestScopes(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseMiddleware<RequestScopeMiddleware>(ScopeName);
    }
}
```

Comment: `InstancePerLifetimeScope()` was all I was looking for - thank you!

Comment: Be aware that by the time your middleware has run that ASP.NET Core internals has already created their request services scope, which means you're basically creating two child scopes per request here. That's not entirely free perf-wise and can have potential side effects when it comes to actual things that are registered instance per lifetime scope. That's why Autofac went with the standard presented by ASP.NET Core, with all the good and bad, and doesn't have tagged scopes in ASP.NET Core for requests.

Comment: @TravisIllig - yes, I know that. In our case it is totally acceptable.

Comment: You might know that, the asker and future readers might not. If you file an issue with ASP.NET Core or Autofac and you're doing this, you're on your own. It's just something to be aware of when going totally custom.

Comment: Agree. Thanks for the note.

Comment: This is what we needed because we have requests where at first a user id is extracted and then stored in a PerRequest scoped object such that any business logic code called subsequently can refer to the acting user by getting this user reference object. If we use Owned Instances with classic PerLifetimeScope registration, these Owned Instances get an empty user referencing object because an Owned Instance lives in a new LifetimeScope. This is why this approach for a PerRequest lifetime scope made our day.

Answer (score 1):

Stop using `InstancePerRequest` and switch to `InstancePerLifetimeScope`. [From the documentation](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#differences-from-asp-net-classic):

> **Use `InstancePerLifetimeScope` instead of `InstancePerRequest`.** In previous ASP.NET integration you could register a dependency as `InstancePerRequest` which would ensure only one instance of the dependency would be created per HTTP request. This worked because Autofac was in charge of setting up the per-request lifetime scope. With the introduction of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, the creation of per-request and other child lifetime scopes is now part of the conforming container provided by the framework, so all child lifetime scopes are treated equally - there’s no special "request level scope" anymore. Instead of registering your dependencies `InstancePerRequest`, use `InstancePerLifetimeScope` and you should get the same behavior. Note if you are creating your own lifetime scopes during web requests, you will get a new instance in these child scopes.

Comment: That's true. However, it's not hard at all to implement exactly the same per-request scopes with autofac in .net core as well. All it takes to do it is small middleware, one extension method to register it and `.InstancePerRequest()` extension itself. Works like a charm.

Comment: @Alexander it may be possible, but that's not what the asker is doing and that's not the way things work by default so... Maybe interesting factoid, but not as helpful in this instance. (Unless you maybe want to add an answer showing that work to help the asker?)

Comment: answer it is. :) It's actually interesting question since I myself was digging the same thing not long ago during old project code migration which made use of `InstancePerRequest()`.